# R shiny: Why do I get invalid 'times' argument

Tags: r, shiny, rep

I have a shiny app, I want to generate a data frame according to user's input:

For instance, users define the sample groups and the corresponding replicates (orange table), shiny app will generate a 1 column dataframe (blue table).

It works fine with users' input.

However, where the input table is empty, I got the `invalid 'times' argument`.

I don't understand why. I use `rep()` function to generate the data frame. I have specifically stated that `if(all(is.na(inFile))) {return(NULL)}`, why it did not work?

Here is my shiny example code:

Thanks a lot for your help.

[image]

```
library(shinyMatrix)

m <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("Group", "Replicates")))
ui = shiny::fluidPage(
  shiny::fluidRow(
    column(6, 
           matrixInput(
             inputId = "matrix",
             value = m,
             class = "character",
             rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = FALSE),
             cols = list(names = TRUE)
             )
           ),
    column(6, tableOutput("table"))
    )
  )

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  inputData <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$matrix
    if(all(is.na(inFile))) {return(NULL)}
    inFile <- as.data.frame(inFile)
    DF <- data.frame(Group = rep(inFile$Group, times = as.numeric(inFile$Replicates)))
    return(DF)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable(inputData(), rownames = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `input$matrix` and `inFile` contain empty character values (""), and not `NA`. If you wanted to `return(NULL)` if either of the input values are empty character values, then you could try `if(any(inFile == "")) {return(NULL)}` or likely better to `validate` the inputs instead...

Comment: @Ben, Thanks lot. It worked. I will `validate` the input.